# Mousedown event in virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Could someone help me with jQuery. I'm newbie at JavaScript, so I get JavaScript code of virtual keyboard for my web app, and trying to modify it to my needs. I need one more button which handles mousedown event. I don't know how to realize it.

I try to do it like this: 
`{ value: "Click", isChar: "false", onclick: "mousedown"}` But It isn't work for me. 
mousedown function should call another function from another file when i click mouse, i couldn't relize it

Comment: Could you post your code or provide us some [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?